# Creating a database that can work with Web/iOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, mysql, mongodb, api

I want to create a database so both my website and mobile app could retrieve/insert info from there. I know how to execute queries with a website, but I have little to none experience with mobile applications. I heard I can't just use any form of database(mysql, mongodb) because they are not compatible or something. so how do I create my database so it will be compatible with android iOS and PC. A few guidelines to get me started would be great :)

Comment: Solution with many advantages is to have an api service between your client and the database. Then it doesn't make much difference which database engine to use.

Comment: First off, if you want your mobile app and website to have the same database at the back is to make an API, the database is irrelevant but i do suggest amazon RDS it is very powerful and not that expensive. so the begin point for you is to create said api and deploy it to a server which you can access from both mobile and website. making web calls to a database from a mobile device is very easy and not much different from doing it in javascript.

Comment: Any suggestion for API ? PHP, nodejs..etc

Comment: Entirely up to you and what you're comfortable/familiar with. With simple data access api there's not much that can go wrong, just follow some tutorial and don't forget about security.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can't use any type of database with mobile application. You can use SQlite for android and iOS application. If you are looking to develop native application then there are other alternatives with iOS like Core-Data, Realm(Swift). On server side i.e for API's you can use MySQL, MongoDB databases.